# Can I create tag for metrics in cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS ALB and querying some metrics like `UnHealthyHostCount` under Application Load Balancer -> TargetGroup. I use this address to query the value `targetgroup/my-service-api/xxxxxxxx`. I wonder whether I can create tags for this metrics. I have many services using the same merics. I'd like to find a way to query a metrics for all my services.

Comment: What about creating a custom metric which would be based on the metrics for the individiual services? With [Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) you could query multiple metrics of interst, and create a new one.

Comment: There are many useful buildin metrics in cloudwatch like `UnHealthyHostCount`. If I create my own one, I have to manually reports unhealthy host count which I don't want to  do. I'd like to leverage metrics provided by AWS